# Xamarin update NuGet problems

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget

When I try to install updates from NuGet, on a fresh install of VS 2017 from Xamarin website, I get this error. Anyone know how to get this update to install? There are a total of 9 updates...they all fail.

```
Severity Code Description Project File  Line Suppression State
Error Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 25.3.1' 
is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.247 constraint: 
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the dependencies, you will see that only `MonoAndroid 7.0` allows `Xamarin.Android.Support.Design >= 23.3.0`:

**Dependencies**

**MonoAndroid 1.0**

Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)

**MonoAndroid 7.0**

Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (>= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (>= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (>= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (>= 23.3.0)

Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (>= 23.3.0)

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

Thus you should ensure your `Target Framework Version / Compile With Version` is 7.0 or higher.

Comment: Thank you,Jon. My bad :(